# python3.6.2 + django1.11.4 + django-mssql1.8 - is this combination supports? Unable to connect sql server from django

Tags: python, sql-server, django, python-3.6, django-mssql

I am using `pthon3.6.2` + `django1.11.4` + `django-mssql1.8` combination for my web application and unable to connect to `sql server` database. Following is the setting I am using in setting.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'DB1',
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'HOST': '192.168.5.245',
        'USER': 'user1',
        'PASSWORD': '123456',
    }
}
```

1. Is this combination supports? i.e. django-mssql1.8 is supported or
   not with other two. The [django-mssql website](https://django-mssql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#dependencies) does not mention
   this
2. If it supports please advise how to resolve.

I am getting the following error :

[image]

Comment: PyODBC is far more better than django-mssql.Check out this [Link](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc).

Comment: I tried the django-pyodbc1.1.0 but did not work. After your comment again searched and used django-pyodbc-azure 1.11.0.0 and it worked!! :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. I still don't know whether that combination supports or not. Instead of django-mssql I am using [django-pyodbc-azure 1.11.0.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pyodbc-azure)

Installation :

```
pip install django-pyodbc-azure
```

Following is the code at settings.py. It workis properly.

```
'default': {
        'NAME': 'DB1',
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'HOST': '192.168.5.245',
        'USER': 'user1',
        'PASSWORD': '123456',
        'OPTIONS' : {
            'driver' : 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0'
        }
    }
```